# How to do File examination in C++

Tags: c++, file, examine

Is there any object oriented method in C++ which is used to examine the file's properties like the `lstat` in C ? Or it's similar to the `File` Class in Java ?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `lstat` in C++, just as you would in C. It's part of POSIX.